# Next.js Controlled input not "Controlled"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, controlled-component

I have a controlled input that should not update when I type. I have stripped the component down to a basic `<input/>` to mitigate any side effects but it still allows me to edit the value.

```
const myComponent = () => {
   const text = 'Hello';
   return(
      <input value={text}/>
   )
}
```

I expect the value to always be `Hello` even when attempting to type in the input, but this is not the case. When I had other components that changed the state, the input would reset back to `Hello`, but only after a render was triggered by another state change. Any ideas what could be happening here? I would include a Codepen, but the code works as expected (no text change allowed) in other places outside my Next.js app

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input value={text} disabled/>
```